# Best Approach for Replay mechanism

Tags: java, json, rest, postman, advanced-rest-client

> In my project, two application running simultaneously, if one is up 
>   and another one is down.(As  expected). The application which  one is
>   down  ,  from that I'll  audit(capture) all failed request and stored
>   into oracle db along with response body.
>
> Here main concern which  approach need to  follow to execute these 
>   all failed request at time by manually to  down application once it is
>   up.  Currently I'm following..,
>
> 1) from audit table , generating  postman supported json file (as a
>   collection) and upload to postman as a collection and running at time
>   a all requests.
>
> 2) Is there any other best approach  to  achieve this ?

Comment: Gather all the failed request. Create a thread and execute requests one by one then save it your database. when other app is up(which was down earlier) then can easily read the data from database

Comment: Failed request details stored into persistence database done ,here down server interacting  different database ,  so i need to  run the request on respective application once it is up.